# should i normalize dependent variable for linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, normalization

If we want to perform a multiple linear regression on the dependent variable $Y$ by independent variables $X_1$,$X_2$, etc., should I normalize the $X_i$ variables only? Or should I also normalize the dependent variable $Y$?

If I normalize $Y$ , how will I interpret the predicted values? Won't the predicted values be in the normalized form? How should I denormalize them to get the exact values?

Also, which is the best normalization method, if my $X_i$ variables are a mixture of both continuous and categorical variables?

Comment: just to add that dont forget to standardize your feature, unles its a feature coming from one hot encoding. this will prevent you dealing with different scale probleme as Ben as in the comment

Comment: Standardization of explanatory variables is usually unnecessary in most applications of ordinary least squares regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your data (especially the residuals of the final regression model) and further context, it is hard to provide you with a definitive answer.

However, when talking about regression in general, your dependent variable does **not** have to be normally distributed. The model's residuals on the other hand, do have to be normally distributed. Look at it this way: one of the assumptions of linear regression is that your independent variables explain the variation in the dependent variable in such a way, that the error around the model's estimated values (== the residuals) of the dependent variable is normally distributed.

Comment: How is it when $ X_1 , X_2 $ have totally different ranges like distance and temperature?